# Access Control Primitives

Tags: access-control

The basic security services are: confidentiality, integrity, authentication, non-repudiation and access control. A primitive for integrity is hash functions, and for authentication is asymmetric cryptography, isn't it?

I'd like to know some Access Control Primitives. I don't know if RBAC, DAC and MAC can be called primitives.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any. Access control is not based on having a strong primitive that you layer everything else around (like how confidentiality and authentication are done).